# Algorithm to un-concatenate words from string without spaces and punctuation

Tags: string, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures, trie

I've been given a problem in my data structures class to find the solution to this problem. It's similar to an interview question. If someone could explain the thinking process or solution to the problem. Pseudocode can be used. So far i've been thinking to use tries to hold the dictionary and look up words that way for efficiency.

This is the problem:

Oh, no! You have just completed a lengthy document when you have an unfortunate Find/Replace mishap. You have accidentally removed all spaces, punctuation, and capitalization in the document. A sentence like "I reset the computer. It still didn't boot!" would become "iresetthecomputeritstilldidntboot". You figure that you can add back in the punctation and capitalization later, once you get the individual words properly separated. Most of the words will be in a dictionary, but some strings, like proper names, will not.

Given a dictionary (a list of words), design an algorithm to find the optimal way of "unconcatenating" a sequence of words. In this case, "optimal" is defined to be the parsing which minimizes the number of unrecognized sequences of characters.

For example, the string "jesslookedjustliketimherbrother" would be optimally parsed as "JESS looked just like TIM her brother". This parsing has seven unrecognized characters, which we have capitalized for clarity.

Comment: I've answered, but I question your cost model. If it's really minimizing the number of unrecognized sequences of characters, then the optimal parsing is one that has a single unrecognized sequence containing the whole string. If it's to minimize the number of unrecognised characters, then the "I" from TIM can be parsed as a word reducing the count to 6 (or even fewer if "ess" or "ti" are words).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use rolling hashes of different lengths to speed up the search.

Comment: This is the closest answer to what my professor made the answer later on. You would put the dictionary in a hash for fast accessing ~O(1) and then you check to see all different word possibilities and place spaces accordingly. Personally, I think that a finite state machine would solve this problem more efficiently, it just requires a little more work (and maybe time) to set up the FSM at first but then it would be O(N) after that, N being the size of the document being manipulated.

Comment: @GusGus:It turns out aho-corasick is a fsm.

Comment: Yeah I didn't know what that was. haha Thank you! Yeah that is exactly what I was talking about. I think that is more efficient but the answer my professor chose must be because setting up the hash table is easier and less time intensive (complexity wise)

Comment: @GusGus: There is a solution for this question in the Cracking the Coding Interview book.

Answer (score 2):

For each index, `n`, into the string, compute the cost `C(n)` of the optimal solution (ie: the number of unrecognised characters in the optimal parsing) starting at that index.

Then, the solution to your problem is `C(0)`.

There's a recurrence relation for `C`. At each `n`, either you match a word of `i` characters, or you skip over character `n`, incurring a cost of 1, and then parse the rest optimally. You just need to find which of those choices incurs the lowest cost.

Let `N` be the length of the string, and let `W(n)` be a set containing the lengths of all words starting at index `n` in your string. Then:

```
C(N) = 0
C(n) = min({C(n+1) + 1} union {C(n+i) for i in W(n)})
```

This can be implemented using dynamic programming by constructing a table of C(n) starting from the end backwards.

If the length of the longest word in your dictionary is L, then the algorithm runs in O(NL) time in the worst case and can be implemented to use O(L) memory if you're careful.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a partial pattern matcher for example aho-corasick algorithm. Basically it's a special space optimized version of a suffix tree.